# divide items in ngFor into two lists

Tags: angular, ngfor

here is my code for a list of check boxes:-

```
<div class="policy-group">
    <p><strong>Interests</strong></p>
        <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let interest of (objAccountSetting != null && objAccountSetting.BasketSettings != null && objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests != null && objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests.length > 0) ? objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests : [];let i = index;">

          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                </div>

                <label class="custom-chck">{{interest?.Name}}
                       <input type="checkbox" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [value]="interest?.Id"  id="{{interest?.Id}}" [(ngModel)]="objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests[i].Checked" id="{{interest?.Id}}">
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
               </label>

               <input type="hidden" name="hdnIntrestId" value="interest?.Id" [(ngModel)]="objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests[i].Id">

    </div>
</div>
```

In the code above I have a ngFor which is rendering a list of interests, the problem I am having is that there are hundreds of interests in the database so ngFor is printing 100s of items. I would like to somehow break the list of checkboxes into several lists side by side on the page so the user does not have to scroll till the end of the page

Comment: Hi, did my answer provide a solution?

Comment: @JMP I did not get a chance to test it yet, I will accept your answer if it helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks, interested to know as flexbox gives a nice solution when testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way would be to do with css using flexbox, which gives horizontal layout for elements within and many options to control the layout e.g:

html:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

If e.g. you want to set to a certain number of checkboxes per row, add this (will set to 5 per row):

```
.flex-container > div {
flex: 1, 0;
width:20%;
text-align:center;
}
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6r6p1j) based on cut down version of your code.

See [Mozilla - concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for details and configuration options.

For your sample, add an extra div inside loop with the class:

```
    <div class="policy-group">
        <p><strong>Interests</strong></p>
<div class="flex-container">
            <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let interest of (objAccountSetting != null && objAccountSetting.BasketSettings != null && objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests != null && objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests.length > 0) ? objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests : [];let i = index;">

              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>

                    <label class="custom-chck">{{interest?.Name}}
                           <input type="checkbox" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [value]="interest?.Id"  id="{{interest?.Id}}" [(ngModel)]="objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests[i].Checked" id="{{interest?.Id}}">
                          <span class="checkmark"></span>
                   </label>

                   <input type="hidden" name="hdnIntrestId" value="interest?.Id" [(ngModel)]="objAccountSetting.BasketSettings.Interests[i].Id">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```